# fill() method doesn't work. Playwright/Python

Tags: python, methods, playwright, playwright-python, playwright-test

I'm writing automated tests using Playwright in PyCharm. I have a method:

python

```
def fill_email_input(self, email="email_value"):
    email_input = self.page.locator(SignInPageLocators.EMAIL_INPUT)
    email_input.fill(email)
```

When I use this method, the `fill` method doesn't work; it locates the field, but it remains empty. If I replace `fill` with `type`, the field gets filled, but the first character of the entered string disappears. If I use the line "email_input.fill(email)" twice, the field gets filled as it should.

The field is found, but no text is entered into the field

Comment: Is this a plain, ordinary field, or is there Javascript associated with it?  I'm wondering if there's a timing thing going on, where it takes time after receiving focus before the field is ready to accept input.  A human would notice, but a robot would.

Comment: @tim-roberts No, time does not pass, I have 2 similar methods with filling in the name and password, in which I use fill(), and in them fill() works correctly, there is also an Email field on another page on which everything works correctly.

Comment: I've had some wonkiness with this before, adding a small wait before and after seems to fix it, it's be nice to have a proper solution though.

Comment: Adding a wait to the method doesn't solve the problem; the test just freezes. The only thing that helps is duplicating the line "email_input.fill(email)"

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. There's nothing wrong with this code per se, only the behavior of a specific website or larger context would make it wrong.

Comment: you should create `minimal working code` so we could simply copy and test it. And you should show (in question) url for this page because all problem can be in HTML or JavaScript. Some pages may use special methods to stop bots/scrapers.

Comment: https://mega.nz/file/XeBElTJR#PjmUyHLDoE5LYx8lmGTwvBsripiW3viB6XWSq22dC5Y reproducing example